# Scrape html page using pandas python multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas

I want to scrape the information of the HTTP link in python. I'm not sure where to start because it isn't organized at all contains multiple pages. I'm used to scraping HTML. I tried read_html and that didn't help.

How would you try to scrape this link? Here is a link: https://portal.charitycommissioner.je/Public-Register/

Answer (score 1):

You want to use chromedriver and describe the action that the driver should take (e.g., clicking on a specific button). For example

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("...").click()
```